# Upgraded to Angular 16: Google Places Autocomplete (ngx-google-places-autocomplete) preventing compilation

Tags: android, ios, angular, ivy, google-places-autocomplete

I'm looking to get support for Google Places Autocomplete for iOS version 16.x (and Android) on mobile devices in portrait mode.
So I've upgraded our Angular web application from 14 to 15 and then to 16, where 15 works fine, but when upgrading to 16 the upgrade goes fine but I'm getting an error when building, see below.
Seems that Google Places Autocomplete (ngx-google-places-autocomplete) is preventing Angular to compile.
Guess it's hard to believe, but this Google Places Autocomplete was lastly updated three years ago, if you go to the npm page ([https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-google-places-autocomplete]). Nobody on the UX team that verified this when the project started seven months ago.
This leads me to these important questions: can we expect to have the library authors of this package to provide support for Angular 16 / Ivy any time soon? Or is this a dead package with no future? What usable alternatives do exist?
See below for the steps I followed and finally the error.
Any help would highly be appreciated, and if there are viable solutions out there (that don't charge the client) then I'm all ears to hear about them too.

Error: src/app/xxx-app.module.ts:76:5 - error NG6002: 'GooglePlaceModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.
76     GooglePlaceModule,
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ngx-google-places-autocomplete/ngx-google-places-autocomplete.module.d.ts:1:22
1 export declare class GooglePlaceModule {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This likely means that the library (ngx-google-places-autocomplete) which declares GooglePlaceModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

TIA!!

Comment: Adding ng version information:

Angular CLI: 16.0.4
Node: 18.16.0
Package Manager: npm 9.6.7
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 16.0.4

@angular-devkit/architect          0.1600.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular      16.0.4
@angular-devkit/core               16.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics         16.0.4
@angular/cdk                       16.0.3
@angular/material                  16.0.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter   16.0.3
@schematics/angular                16.0.4
rxjs                               7.5.7
typescript                         4.9.5

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is another thread posted recently : [ngx-google-places-autocomplete not working with angular 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76668397/ngx-google-places-autocomplete-not-working-with-angular-16/76800066#76800066)

Ngx-google-places-autocomplete is incompatible with Angular 16. revert back to 15 or use JavaScript temporarely to do autocompletion.

Have you tried using the Angular Material NGX package for google ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-extensions/google-maps-autocomplete