# ngx-google-places-autocomplete not working with angular 16

Tags: angular16, ngx-google-places-autocomplete

'GooglePlaceModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

233     GooglePlaceModule,
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/ngx-google-places-autocomplete/ngx-google-places-autocomplete.module.d.ts:1:22
1 export declare class GooglePlaceModule {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This likely means that the library (ngx-google-places-autocomplete) which declares GooglePlaceModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

Just update my application from 14 to 16

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@CanadianDjiinn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76800066/17332307), the package has not been updated since november 2020.

I was having the same problem after upgrading angular (v14 ==> v16). I was able to fix this by switching to [**@angular-magic/ngx-gp-autocomplete**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-magic/ngx-gp-autocomplete)

The update should only take a few minutes.

The code is based on ngx-google-places-autocomplete, but it applies some fixes and improvements.

Answer (score 0):

This package has not been updated for 3 yers if I am not mistaken. Hopefully some super awesome person will be able to get it working with Angular Ivy.

There are a few blogs that have been written in the past 30 days that suggest that ngx-google-places-autocomplete works out of the box. I posted some questions for help, hopefully they get back to me :)

This blog seems to be posted in June and suggest that Angular 16 still works.
https://www.laratutorials.com/angular-14-google-places-autocomplete/

This blog here is the same, but was posted in last week
https://www.tutsmake.com/google-places-autocomplete-in-angular-16/